# How to uninstall or replace Joy Launcher?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, launcher, joy-launcher

This morning my Android mobile started asking for permissions for a "Joy Launcher" app that I've never seen (or at least noticed before).  This *appears* to be an official app from the manufacturer.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tct.launcher

I also found this article indicating that Google recently discontinued their Google Now Launcher, but I'm uncertain as to whether this has any bearing on my situation.

http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/02/03/google-will-discontinue-google-now-launcher-coming-weeks/

My biggest concern is that it's suddenly asking for unneeded permissions.  It seems unusual to me.  I haven't been able to disable it.  Can anyone shed some light on what's happening and/or any insight as to how I can remove or replace it?

Comment: I'd first start to check whether it's a pre-installed or user-installed app (in the latter case, and being sure *you* didn't install it, you might have a malware problem – in the former case, it might just have been a "regular update" with the new version requiring additional permissions). To do so, go to *Settings › Apps* and check whether "Joy Launcher" appears under "Installed". If it's there, it's user-installed. If not, check in "All", where pre-installed apps are listed as well. PS: That's also a place where you can uninstall or at least disable an app.

Comment: @Izzy I'm pretty sure that it's not preinstalled.  I use a startup manager to turn off unneeded applications at startup (e.g. Fedex, etc.).  Malware was initially my concern, but I'm reasonably certain that the app is from Alcatel, my mobile's manufacturer, since two other apps that I know came preinstalled on the phone show the same author in the Google Play store.  I must admit that my experience with launchers is very limited.  At this point I'm mainly interested in finding out if or how I can replace it.  I'm not a fan of unsubscribed, forced updates.

Comment: Jim, if it didn't come preinstalled, then who installed it if not you? If you suspect Alcatel: was there some "system update" from them that could have added it? If not: installing apps without user consent is malicious behavior in my eyes. And have you meanwhile checked in the place I suggested? To help you, we need those details.

Comment: @Izzy, unfortunately my mobile doesn't give me a breakdown of user-defined apps.  When I drill into the app settings, the Disable button is disabled (greyed out). Tapping the Force Stop button seems to have no effect. I agree that it definitely feels like malicious behavior.  There are a lot of recent comments from people with a similar experience in the Google Play store.  Just a few minutes ago it even blew away all my screens, as it's done to so many others. :(

Comment: "the Disable button is disabled (greyed out)." Just the fact that there is a "Disable" button tells us it's a pre-installed app. What's more, it seems to be protected (hence "greyed out") – which is a good idea *if it's the only launcher installed* as otherwise, if you'd disable it, you could no longer use your device. OK, that mystery solved: You could install another launcher (a selection is available [in my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher), make that the default (tap the home button, select it, chose "always") and see if you then can disable JL.

Comment: If by "pre-installed" you mean that it was installed by the manufacturer, I tend to agree.  However, it definitely was not installed when I initially received the phone.  This app appeared only several days ago in what appears to have been a forced mass update from the manufacturer.  I will try installing another launcher and let you know how it goes.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry: the term "pre-installed" is a bit misleading. Technically, I should have better used the terms "system app". From what I've learned in our exchange, I agree it must have been installed by that update from the manufacturer/provider who obviously intended to make it the "default launcher" (and the only launcher "pre-installed", which is why you cannot disable it). I somehow doubt installing an alternative launcher will enable you to disable JL (without "special tricks" or "root powers"), but at least you will have an alternative to use.

Comment: PS: If you're satisfied by a replacement launcher, please see [pm hide VS pm disable — the identity crisis](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/128949/16575) for how to somehow get rid of JL (pointer: `adb shell pm disable` should do the trick, no root required). Same topic: [How can I disable a stock app that has its Disable button greyed out?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/95975/16575) But again, don't try that unless you have an alternative launcher installed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Izzy.  In the end, I haven't been able to disable the app via Android's App settings, but after installing a different launcher, I was able to prevent Joy Launcher from being loaded at startup using the Startup Manager (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager) app, so in effect it's at least using zero resouces now.

Comment: That's a good first step – and probably a good compromise. Have you tried `pm disable`? Then its icon would also be removed from the launcher and save you some space there. Btw: Have you considered to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with a short step-by-step guide? Might be helpful to others (there were already several "me too" posts we had to remove here).

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get around to trying `pm disable`.  Switching launchers was good enough for me.  I'll post my workaround below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up disabling Joy Launcher and installing [another launcher of my choice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerpro).  Joy Launcher can be removed from the startup items using any startup manager.  I very recently switched to the [All-In-One Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.toolbox.full) app, since the Startup Manager app I mentioned above in the comments has gone flaky lately.