# Weird Octopus icon, Joy Launcher on Alcatel

Tags: joy-launcher

this weird thing happened today, an octopus icon appeared on screen. Alcatel. It's annoying. Linked to Joy Launcher, which can't be disabled. 
Any idea how I can turn it off?
Not the same as other question about Joy Launcher

[image: A]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall or replace Joy Launcher?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177502/how-to-uninstall-or-replace-joy-launcher)

Comment: @beeshyams Don't jump to a conclusion too fast.

Comment: Somebody mentioned that the icon looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRcsS.jpg). I presume this to be an overlay so I suggest you try Andrew T's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/136145/96277) if you're on Android Marshmallow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went into Settings → Apps → Joy Launcher, and then pressed a little cog in the top right which resets Joy Launcher back to its default (original) state. But it also resets your home page back to default.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too and I couldn't get rid of it. When I went in to the settings I didn't see/have the cog that was mentioned above so there was no way to change any of the settings. I tried to force stop it but it would immediately start back up.

What I did to get rid of it was to install a different launcher. There are several Ad free ones including: Cheetah, Arrow, and Nova.

That got rid of it. The Octopus was really annoying and there should have been some warning before they did that.

Comment: You may want to be careful about recommending Cheetah apps based on a new report out about Cheetah, and Google Play actions against them. See this: [https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/).

Answer (score 0):

I too was the victim of the rotten Joy Launcher. I think I have now stopped it and now we have a happy Alcatel cell phone. 
 I did a lot of things, but basically - sorry do not have the cell to hand. 
 I uninstalled Joy Launcher (from version 7.0 to version 5??) and clicked on Force Stop. Then I uninstalled Updates (from version 7.0 to version 5??) and clicked on Force Stop. 
 Within Play Store, I selected 'do not install when connected to Wireless' and 'manual install'.
 There is one last 'manual install' option which I think is within settings.
 The octopus is gone and Joy Launcher doesn't bug me anymore. Yippee!

Answer (score 0):

try these steps :

1. Go to Setting-> Apps
2. Tap on Joy Launcher

   inside joy launcher, select uninstall updates then, select storage and clear data,it will work 100%

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Alcatel really screwed up a lot of the factory apps. IDK who the dev is now but they need to fire him or her. To return joy launcher to the factory version (which is called onetouch) go to settings, apps, and scroll down to Joy launcher. Go ahead and click it then in the upper right hand corner there are three dots. Push the dots (menu) and uncheck the box to uninstall updates. That will bring it back to the way you bought it. Make sure you disable the automatic updates for Joy Launcher aka Onetouch. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Factory reset disable auto updates was my solution, not the best but was so freaked out that it had to be done.

Answer (score -1):

Apps > Settings > Launcher and it allowed me to uninstall updates back to factory version. That got rid of it and all the other nonsense that showed up on my Alcatel yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

I disabled my Wi-Fi first just to be safe, then uninstalled the "updates" (the three dots in the top right), thus restoring the app to factory settings.

Comment: I believe this is a better fit to David's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180984/96277) as a comment. Your answer adds nothing new or of value other than that you disabled Wi-Fi first but didn't mention why it was best to be done so?