# Is there a way to grant myself MANAGE_USERS permission while inside the adb shell?

Tags: adb, permissions, shell

The thing is that I'm fed up of some stock adware apps on my Micromax phone and want to disable them for good. So, as per [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114798/38760), I used adb shell to disable the app, but I'm getting the following error:

```
shell@Q4260:/ $ pm hide com.micromax.trendingapps
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.
1|shell@Q4260:/ $
```

The error message indicates that I need `android.permission.MANAGE_USERS` to achieve that. So I even tried granting that permission to the shell app, but no use!

```
shell@Q4260:/ $ pm grant com.android.shell android.permission.MANAGE_USERS     
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.android.shell has not requested permission android.permission.MANAGE_USERS
1|shell@Q4260:/ $
```

Is there any other way to get myself that permission?

Finally, the smart-phone is Micromax Q4260 running Marshmallow if that matters. This could probably be solved by rooting, but I don't have any intention of rooting as it could be risky on this little known model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with a little help from Google and XDA Forums. Though this doesn't answer the exact title question, I found [an alternative way to disable OEM bloatware on Android M+](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/) without requiring `MANAGE_USERS` permission or root:

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.micromax.trendingapps
```

(you may use or not the `-k` option, which is to keep the data and cache directories)

Comment: Your hint allowed me to remove the apps "AudioFX" and "FM Radio" to clean up a bit further my phone (Redmi 5A - LineageOS 15.1). Thanks!